# How to find the closest rotation

Tags: algorithm

Consider points Y given in increasing order from [0,T). We are to consider these points as lying on a circle of circumference T.  Now consider points X also from [0,T) and also lying on a circle of circumference T.

We say the distance between X and Y is the sum of the absolute distance between the each point in X and its closest point in Y recalling that both are considered to be lying in a circle.  Write this distance as Delta(X, Y).

I am trying to find a quick way of determining a rotation of X which makes this distance as small as possible.

My code for making some data to test with is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect_left

def simul(rate, T):
    time = np.random.exponential(rate)
    times = [0]
    newtime = times[-1]+time
    while (newtime < T):
        times.append(newtime)
        newtime = newtime+np.random.exponential(rate)
    return times[1:]
```

For each point I use this function to find its closest neighbor.

```
def takeClosest(myList, myNumber, T):
    """
    Assumes myList is sorted. Returns closest value to myNumber in a circle of circumference T.

    If two numbers are equally close, return the smallest number.
    """
    pos = bisect_left(myList, myNumber)
    before = myList[pos - 1]
    after = myList[pos%len(myList)]
    if after - myNumber < myNumber - before:
       return after
    else:
       return before
```

So the distance between two circles is:

```
def circle_dist(timesY, timesX):
    dist = 0
    for t in timesX:
        closest_number = takeClosest(timesY, t, T)
        dist += np.abs(closest_number - t)
    return dist
```

So to make some data we just do

```
#First make some data

T = 5000

timesX = simul(1, T)
timesY = simul(10, T)
```

Finally to rotate circle timesX by offset we can

```
timesX = [(t + offset)%T for t in timesX]
```

In practice my timesX and timesY will have about 20,000 points each.

> Given timesX and timesY, how can I quickly find (approximately) which rotation of timesX gives
>   the smallest distance to timesY?

Comment: Apparently by "absolute distance" you mean distance *along the circle* rather than standard Euclidean distance (`sqrt(2) * T/pi * sqrt(1 - cos(x - y))`). Yes?

Comment: @Dougal Yes, along the circle. To be honest, if another measure of distance along the circle makes things easier I would happy to consider that too.

Comment: @Dougal: I think (didn't prove it yet) that the Euclidean distance corresponds to the difference in angles (mod 2\pi). Thus if two points x1 and y1 are further apart than two other points x2 and y2, then the difference of the angles between x1 and y1 is larger than the difference in angles between x2 and y2 (mod 2\pi). Regard x1, x2, y1, y2 as complex numbers in polar coordinates

Comment: You probably don't want to minimize the sum ob absolute distances (SAD) but sum of squared distances (SSD). E.g. for 1D points on a straight axis ```X=[0]``` and ```Y[x,x+10]``` the SAD is 10 for all -10 < x < 0, but the SSQ has an absolute minimum at x = -5.

Comment: @Falko you may be right that ssd is better. However the distance is only from 0 to the closest point in my code so it isn't quite like your example. In other words the minimum sad is 0 for your example.

Comment: @user2179021: Sure, it was just an analogy. On a circle you want to wrap around, i.e. go from T-1 to 0.

Comment: @Falko I would be very happy with a ssd based answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

Distance along the circle between a single point and a set of points is a piecewise linear function of rotation. The critical points of this function are the points of the set itself (zero distance) and points midway between neighbouring points of the set (local maximums of distance). Linear coefficients of such function are ±1.

Sum of such functions is again piecewise linear, but now with a quadratic number of critical points. Actually all these functions are the same, except shifted along the argument axis. Linear coefficients of the sum are integers.

To find its minimum one would have to calculate its value in all critical points.

I don'see a way to significantly reduce the amount of work needed, but 1,600,000,000 points is not such a big deal anyway, especially if you can spread the work between several processors.

To calculate sum of two such functions, represent the summands as sequences of critical points and associated coefficients to the left and to the right of each critical point. Then just merge the two point sequences while adding the coefficients.

Comment: +1 for using the right terminology and suggesting parallelization.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your (original) problem with a sweep line algorithm. The trick is to use the right "discretization". Imagine cutting your circle up into two strips:

```
X: x....x....x..........x................x.........x...x
Y: .....x..........x.....x..x.x...........x.............
```

Now calculate the `score = 5+0++1+1+5+9+6`.

The key observation is that if we rotate `X` very slightly (right say), some of the points will improve and some will get worse. We can call this the "differential". In the above example the differential would be `1 - 1 - 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 + 1` because the first point is matched to something on its right, the second point is matched to something under it or to its left etc.

Of course, as we move `X` more, the differential will change. However only as many times as the matchings change, which is never more than `|X||Y|` but probably much less.

The proposed algorithm is thus to calculate the initial score and the time (X position) of the next change in differential. Go to that next position and calculate the score again. Continue until you reach your starting position.

Comment: This is an intriguing method i would like to test. Would you be able to provide more detailed pseudocode or even code?

Comment: This is basically the same as n.m.'s solution. You just move from one 'critical point' to the next, which may make it cheaper to calculate. If things are unclear I'd be happy to clarify or review your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good example for the [iterative closest point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) (ICP) algorithm:

It repeatedly matches each point with its closest neighbor and moves all points such that the mean squared distance is minimized. (Note that this corresponds to minimizing the *sum* of squared distances.)

```py
import pylab as pl

T = 10.0
X = pl.array([3, 5.5, 6])
Y = pl.array([1, 1.5, 2, 4])

pl.clf()
pl.subplot(1, 2, 1, polar=True)
pl.plot(X / T * 2 * pl.pi, pl.ones(X.shape), 'r.', ms=10, mew=3)
pl.plot(Y / T * 2 * pl.pi, pl.ones(Y.shape), 'b+', ms=10, mew=3)

circDist = lambda X, Y: (Y - X + T / 2) % T - T / 2

while True:
    D = circDist(pl.reshape(X, (-1, 1)), pl.reshape(Y, (1, -1)))
    closestY = pl.argmin(D**2, axis = 1)
    distance = circDist(X, Y[closestY])
    shift = pl.mean(distance)
    if pl.absolute(shift) < 1e-3:
        break
    X = (X + shift) % T

pl.subplot(1, 2, 2, polar=True)
pl.plot(X / T * 2 * pl.pi, pl.ones(X.shape), 'r.', ms=10, mew=3)
pl.plot(Y / T * 2 * pl.pi, pl.ones(Y.shape), 'b+', ms=10, mew=3)
```

Important properties of the proposed solution are:

- The ICP is an iterative algorithm. Thus it depends on an initial approximate solution. Furthermore, it won't always converge to the global optimum. This mainly depends on your data and the initial solution. If in doubt, try evaluating the ICP with different starting configurations and choose the most frequent result.
- The current implementation performs a *directed* match: It looks for the closest point in `Y` relative to each point in `X`. It might yield different matches when swapping `X` and `Y`.
- Computing all pair-wise distances between points in `X` and points in `Y` might be intractable for large point clouds (like 20,000 points, as you indicated). Therefore, the line `D = circDist(...)` might get replaced by a more efficient approach, e.g. not evaluating all possible pairs.
- All points contribute to the final rotation. If there are any outliers, they might distort the `shift` significantly. This can be overcome with a robust average like the `median` or simply by excluding points with large `distance`.

Comment: Do you do squared distance between all pairs? Doesn't that mean that `y` points far from `x` points become much more important than close ones? Just the opposite of what the OP intended?

Comment: Yes, far points (or "outliers" as they are called in the field of adjustment computations) contribute to the solution more than usually intended. But minimizing the squared distance is what everyone does when, e.g., computing the mean. (Minimizing SAD whouldn't yield a distinct mean.) I guess it depends on the application whether you want to use SAD or SSD, whether sweep line or ICP. I really like your solution for its speed and [*convexity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization)!