# Calculating Mean Squared Error through Matrix Arithmetic on Numpy Matrices of Binary Images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have 2 binary images, one is a ground truth, and one is an image segmentation that I produced.

I am trying to calculate the mean squared distance ...

[image]

```
Let G = {g1, g2, . . . , gN} be the points in the ground truth boundary.
Let B = {b1, b2, . . . , bM} be the points in the segmented boundary.
Define d(p, p0) be a measure of distance between points p and p0 (e.g. Euclidean, city block, etc.)
```

between the two images using the following algorithm.

```
def MSD(A,G):
    '''
    Takes a thresholded binary image, and a ground truth img(binary), and computes the mean squared absolute difference
    :param A: The thresholded binary image
    :param G: The ground truth img
    :return:
    '''
    sim = np.bitwise_xor(A,G)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,sim.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,sim.shape[1]):
            if (sim[i,j] == True):
                min = 9999999
                for k in range(0,sim.shape[0]):
                    for l in range(0,sim.shape[1]):
                        if (sim[k, l] == True):
                            e = abs(i-k) + abs(j-l)
                            if e < min:
                                min = e
                                mink = k
                                minl = l
                sum += min
    return sum/(sim.shape[0]*sim.shape[1])
```

This algorithm is too slow though and never completes.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871200/how-to-compute-mean-squared-distance-of-the-segmented-boundary-from-the-ground-t) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338392/how-to-find-the-closest-rotation/25339938) (Answer 3) might show method of how to get the mean squared error using Matrix arithmetic, but I do not understand how these examples make any sense or why they work.

Comment: Your code does not match the equation. Your code, by computing on the symmetric difference (xor), is symmetric. If I swap `A` and `G` I get the same result. This is not true for the equation, this is not a symmetric distance measure. Pixels in `B` (`A`) that are not in `G` increase the mean distance. Pixels in `G` that are not in `B` do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand your formula and code correctly, you have one (binary) image `B` and a (ground truth) image `G`. "Points" are defined by the pixel positions where either image has a `True` (or at least nonzero) value. From your `bitwise_xor` I deduce that both images have the same shape `(M,N)`.

So the quantity `d^2(b,g)` is at worst an `(M*N, M*N)`-sized array, relating each pixel of `B` to each pixel of `G`. It's even better: we only need a shape `(m,n)` if there are `m` nonzeros in `B` and `n` nonzeros in `G`. Unless your images are huge we can get away with keeping track of this large quantity. This will cost memory but we will win a lot of CPU time by vectorization. So then we only have to find the minimum of this distance with respect to every `n` possible value, for each `m`. Then just sum up each minimum. Note that the solution below uses extreme vectorization, and it can easily eat up your memory if the images are large.

Assuming Manhattan distance (with the square in `d^2` which seems to be missing from your code):

```
import numpy as np

# generate dummy data
M,N = 100,100
B = np.random.rand(M,N) > 0.5
G = np.random.rand(M,N) > 0.5

def MSD(B, G):
    # get indices of nonzero pixels
    nnz_B = B.nonzero() # (x_inds, y_inds) tuple, x_inds and y_inds are shape (m,)
    nnz_G = G.nonzero() # (x_inds', y_inds') each with shape (n,)

    # np.array(nnz_B) has shape (2,m)
    # compute squared Manhattan distance
    dist2 = abs(np.array(nnz_B)[...,None] - np.array(nnz_G)[:,None,:]).sum(axis=0)**2 # shape (m,n)
    # alternatively: Euclidean for comparison:
    #dist2 = ((np.array(nnz_B)[...,None] - np.array(nnz_G)[:,None,:])**2).sum(axis=0)

    mindist2 = dist2.min(axis=-1) # shape (m,) of minimum square distances

    return mindist2.mean() # sum divided by m, i.e. the MSD itself

print(MSD(B, G))
```

If the above uses too much memory we can introduce a loop over the elements of `nnz_B`, and only vectorize in the elements of `nnz_G`. This will take more CPU power and less memory. This trade-off is typical for vectorization.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it might _look_ symmetric but it isn't. It's exactly what the formula says. The `dist2` pairwise distance is "symmetric" (just like `d^2(b,g)`), but minimization happens in its second dimension and summation in its first. If that's not convincing enough: `MSD(B, G) != MSD(G, B)` and if I change the metric to Euclidean I get the exact same result as you do ;) But you had me going there for a second!

Comment: Yes, I had myself going there for a minute. :) Sorry, I’m still getting used to Numpy’s way of indexing. You are indeed taking the minimum along one dimension of the 2D distance matrix, then summing along the other. Makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient method for calculating this distance is using the Distance Transform. SciPy has an implementation in the ndimage package: [scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html).

The idea is to compute a distance transform for the background of the ground-truth image `G`. This leads to a new image `D` that is 0 for each pixel that is nonzero in `G`, and for each zero pixel in `G` there will be the distance to the nearest nonzero pixel.

Next, for each nonzero pixel in `B` (or `A` in the code that you posted), you look at the corresponding pixel in `D`. This is the distance to `G` for that pixel. So, simply average all the values in `D` for which `B` is nonzero to obtain your result.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

# Create some test data
img = pp.imread('erika.tif')         # a random image
G = img > 120                        # the ground truth
img = img + np.random.normal(0, 20, img.shape)
B = img > 120                        # the other image

D = nd.morphology.distance_transform_edt(~G)
msd = np.mean(D[B]**2)
```